# Create table name as concatenated string

Tags: postgresql, string-concatenation, amazon-redshift, create-table

I'm using Amazon Redshift via SQL workbench.
I need to create a table (actually multiple but...babysteps) whose name is constructed by concatenating 2 strings.

The following statement works:

```
CREATE TABLE "public.user_111111" (
user_id int,
event_id int,
)
```

But the following one does not:

```
CREATE TABLE "public."||"user_111112" (
user_id int,
event_id int,
)
```

the error is:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "||";
```

Can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong in the second statement?

Thank you

Comment: You need dynamic-sql. Identifiers have to be known at compile time. Identifiers should be **`literal`** but  `"public."||"user_111112"` is expression.

Comment: Does Amazon Redshift support dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Use `execute` command (dynamic-sql):

Just easy like this:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE 
  vSQL      TEXT;
  vMYSCHEMA TEXT;
  vMYTABLE  TEXT;
BEGIN
    vMYSCHEMA = 'public';
    vMYTABLE  = 'user_111112';

    vSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' || vMYSCHEMA || '.' || vMYTABLE || ' (user_id int, event_id int)';
    EXECUTE vSQL;

END;
$$
;
```

or

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || 'public' || '.' || 'user_111112'|| ' (user_id int, event_id int)';
END;
$$
;
```

Comment: Both solutions result in: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "DO"; I'm not sure Amazon Redshift supports this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As lad2025 suggested, you could use *Dynamic SQL* to do that.

## HOWEVER

This is a terrible idea to put DOTS in your table names. It has been asked on DBA site: [Is it okay to put dots in SQL Server database names?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/is-it-okay-to-put-dots-in-sql-server-database-names)

Quoting answer by [Marek Grzenkowicz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/is-it-okay-to-put-dots-in-sql-server-database-names/1175#1175)

> Over the years I found out that many people have trouble understanding
> the four-part naming convention even though it seems pretty obvious:
>
> ```
> server_name.database_name.schema_name.object_name
> ```
>
> Imagine what will happen if they see something like this:
>
> ```
> MAIN-SQL.[MyApp.Sales].hr.CompetitorsProducts
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> [MAIN-SQL\EXPRESS].[MyApp.Sales].sch_HR.[Products From.Our-Competitors]
> ```
>
> Keeping things **simple** is important.

I would suggest not putting dots in your tables either. You'll harden your own (or someones else) life by doing that.

Comment: I think what is trying to do is create a table inside "public" schema. So it is just fine to `create table public.mytable`.

Comment: I always thought that if you quote some object, it acts as a standalone. I can be wrong though

Comment: I'm trying to add the tables in the public schema, the table's name does not contain a dot, it should be just "user_111112"